# Spark Streaming: Aggregating values across batches

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We've a Spark Streaming job that calculates some values in each batch. What we need to do now is aggregate values across ALL batches. What is the best strategy to do this in Spark Streaming. Should we use 'Spark Accumulators' for this?

Comment: I have same issue, did you find solution? Do you mean Spark Streaming or Structed Streaming?

Comment: Check out 'Spark Structured Stateful Streaming'. It is designed for that purpose. Working well for us so far although we've to do stress testing. Hopefully, we can avoid OutOfMemoryErrors in Executors that a few people have reported. Try Spark 2.4 or above.

Comment: if i correctly got it, this way join() few streams combining withWatermark(). Is it single aproach? If my timewindow is 24h or greate and i need to combine more then 2 events of different streams it will quickly leads to OutOfMemoryErrors. How do you think about such way: to create in-memory object which properties presents set of events,  processing different streams, aggregate some data, and then poppulate object. This object can be inherited from a Spark Accumulator or it can be a outside stored object (e.g. in-memory database).